# PouchDb - find() data even fieldtypes ismissing

Tags: pouchdb

Im currently learning pouchDb query. And want to get the data even the fieldtype is not there.
i want to find the data **hide: true** and **hide: fieldtype is null**.

**Before**

```
db.find({
       selector: {
          _id: {
              $gt: 'Tenant_ClPost_',
              $lt: 'Tenant_ClPost_\ufff0'
            }, 
          }
        },
       fields: ['_id', 'hide', 'city']
      }).then(function (response) {
        common.displayJSON(response);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        common.displayMessage(err);
      });
```

At first **Results**

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_id": "Tenant_ClPost_001",
      "hide": "true",
      "city": "losangeles"
    },
    {
      "_id": "Tenant_ClPost_002",
      "hide": "false",
      "city": "losangeles"
    },
    {
      "_id": "Tenant_ClPost_003",
      "city": "losangeles"
    }
  ]
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**After** i added this filter

```
selector: {
            _id: {
              $gt: 'Tenant_ClPost_',
              $lt: 'Tenant_ClPost_\ufff0'
            }, 
            $or: [
              {
                hide: 'true'
              },
              {
                hide: null
              }
            ],
}
```

**This is the result i want**

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_id": "Tenant_ClPost_001",
      "hide": "true",
      "city": "losangeles"
    },
    {
      "_id": "Tenant_ClPost_003",
      "city": "losangeles"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it hehehe my bad

```
selector: {
            _id: {
              $gt: 'Tenant_ClPost_',
              $lt: 'Tenant_ClPost_\ufff0'
            }, 
            hide: {$ne: 'false'},
          },
```